# Does descendantOf only accept a single value?

Tags: craft4, plugin-sprig, descendantof

I have a products page on which I'm filtering with Sprig.
There are some categories in the form of checkboxes.
These categories have some subcategories.
The categories are a structured section with nested categories.

Example:

- Category 1

  - Subcategory a
  - Subcategory b
- Category 2

  - Subcategory c
  - Subcategory d

What I currently got working is to show the level 2 categories filters based on the chosen main category.
What does not work is doing the same but for 2 main categories at the same time.

When the user clicks `Category 1` I want to a query to return `Subcategory a` and `Subcategory b`.

When the user clicks `Category 1` AND `Category 2` I want to a query to return `Subcategory a`, `Subcategory b`, `Subcategory c` and `Subcategory d`.

My query:

```
{% set typeOptions = craft.entries()
 .section('categories')
 .orderBy('title ASC')
 .descendantOf(subcategories|join(','))
 .descendantDist(1)
%}
```

The reason why I am using `join` is because `descendantOf` does not accept an array and it seems it also does not accept comma separated string.
It does accept a non comma separated string. I'm guessing it converts it to an INT internally.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you let us know what subcategories is defined as in your codebase? Seeing how you defined it will help us know what data type it is and whether that's a factor

Comment: It's all just a big structured section. And I'm trying to get the title field.

Comment: Right, but how are you calling it? Depending how it could be an object, an ID value...